# Arduino LilyPad and nRF8001 module wiring

Tags: bluetooth

I am trying to wire up a nRF8001 BLE module with the LilyPad board, as the title says.

The problem is that if I wire them up I am not more able to see the nRF8001 module during the scan phase with the nRF UART 2.0 app ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nordicsemi.nrfUARTv2&hl=it for Android). INstead, if I wire the nRF8001 up with the Arduino Uno rev3 I can correctly exchanging messages from the serial monior to the app and viceversa.

Since the LilyPad is quite equals the the Arduino in terms of processor and pinout, I am wondering what I am doing wrong.

The wirings is the following:

```
LilyPad   <--->   nRF8001
  +                 Vin
  -                 GND
pin #2              RDY
pin #9              RST
pin #10             REQ
pin #11             MOSI
pin #12             MISO
pin #13             SCK
```

Does anyone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Filippo

Comment: How are you powering the LilyPad? Check the current and voltage levels.

Comment: Lilypad is powered via the FTDI USB adapter, so should be 5V, isn't it?

Comment: Should I use the 6-pins header (2x3) in the cebnter of the board near the processor for the SPI connection?